# How to send messages as websocket client in c++ to a server?

Tags: c++, websocket, client, send

I've a little problem in sendine my messages to the server.
It probably send them and the server recieve them, but i have no real idea how to mask them correctly.
I know this is actually the way:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2
But I'm not understanding a lot of it.
It would be nice if someone could share a whole pseudocode what actually need to be done from the plain message until the writing into the buffer.
I also searched here a lot for information but mostly they advice libs or directly the link. The problem is that libs are nice, but i've actually done already all i need. Only the sending  mask is missing.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you send the message with mask bit off?

When mask bit is set, the server expect 4 bytes mask to present, and the payload is XOR'd with

```
for ( size_t i=0; i<packet_len; i++ ) {
    packet[i] = payload[i] ^ mask_bits[i&3];
}
```

---

EDIT: Adding more detail.

I assume you have done the Upgrade handshake, the actual bytes to send to network for communication are:

```
[flag][mask_bit, len][extended length][mask][payload]
```

Where:

- flag: one byte, read the manual, note that I have not tried fragment.
- mask bit, one bit located at highest bit of second byte.
- len: 7 bits of second byte. If len is 126, real len is 16 bit field of extended length. if it is 127, extended length is 64-bit.
- mask: present only if mask bit is set, it's 4 bytes using to XOR the payload.
- payload: actual bytes to send

For example, to send "Hello" to server in binary mode, you do:

- flag: 0x82, "Final packet in frame" and "Binary mode"
- mask bit: 1
- len: 6
- mask: 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44
- payload: "Hello", 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x00

The masked payload is: 0x48^0x11, 0x65^0x22, 0x6C^0x33, 0x6C^0x44, 0x6F^0x11, 0x00^0x22
=> 0x59, 0x47, 0x5F, 0x28, 0x7E, 0x22

The whole stream is: 0x82, 0x86, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x59, 0x47, 0x5F, 0x28, 0x7E, 0x22

Comment: I probably don't i can send message with mask bit off. I have also issues in follow you :-) I'm probably a newbie on C++. It would be nice if you could give me more explanation about the variables you used there. Maybe some more details to my server, as websocket i'm using currently a [PHP Class](https://code.google.com/p/php-websocket-server/source/browse/trunk/ws%20api.php)

Comment: One good thing, the server doesn't kick me anymore in case of an invalid message, but it's still not working somehow for me...  `string convert(string message) {
  char msg[1024];
  char mask[4];
  mask[0] = '0x11';
  mask[1] = '0x22';
  mask[2] = '0x33';
  mask[3] = '0x44';
  int len = message.size(), y=0;
  msg[0] = '0x82'; msg[1] = mask[0]; msg[2] = mask[1]; msg[3] = mask[2]; msg[4] = mask[3];
  
  string hex = strToHex(message);
  for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    msg[i+5] = hex[i] ^ mask[i&3];
  }
  return msg+hex;
}
` Do you see there any issue? The strToHex is working fine.

Comment: you don't need quote for hex number

Comment: Hm it didn't solve the problem. As i said I'm a beginner on C++ :-) However i made a small mistake, its not `return msg+hex;` its only `return msg;` But also not the problem :-(